# Runtime erro in log cat

Tags: android

I can't identify the error exactly. MY application works normal. But I when I navigate through activities in app I notice these errors in log cat in red colors but application doesn't crash

```
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-08 07:13:09.363: E/StrictMode(1067):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-08 07:13:09.413: W/ActivityManager(755): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@414efec0
01-08 07:13:09.413: W/Trace(1067): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-08 07:13:09.413: W/Trace(1067): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-08 07:13:23.563: W/Trace(1005): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-08 07:13:23.573: W/Trace(1005): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
01-08 07:13:54.157: D/ExchangeService(1067): Received deviceId from Email app: null
```

Can anybody explain what is going on here

Comment: I recommend that you add a filter to your `logcat`, with your package name as the "application name". That way you'll have a better overview of the output from your app. :)

Answer (score 1):

You aapplication is not crashing because the Error is E/StrictMode ,when app is crashed Error is reported as E/AndroidRuntime, seems that you have enabled strictmode checking in your app,it reports possible errors and that can be corrected

Comment: does it mean that I don't want to worry about this?